# After disabling web security I still cannot overcome same origin policy

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe

I am using google chrome version 43.0.2357.81 on OS X and attempting to display a webpage within an iframe.
ie:

I followed this link with instructions to disable web security and found it helpful for displaying local files within iframes but I am still encountering the same origin error when trying to display disparate web pages.

[Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

I ran the command  open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security in terminal and received the banner message confirming that it worked:

*You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --disable-web-security. Stability and security will suffer.*

However when I view my webpage in chrome I still got a same origin error and was unable to view the site within the iframe.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with Chrome itself; the server you call within the iframe sends back a http header with

```
X-Frame-Options  SAMEORIGIN
```

setting. Even "chrome.exe --user-data-dir=c:\tmp\chrome2  --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security" does not disable the iframe same origin check in Chrome. The only option you have is to switch the X-Frame-Options of your server to

```
X-Frame-Options  ALLOWALL
```

(if you can).